# Recognizing \r or \n with stringstream and char*

Tags: c++, string

I am having trouble reading a newline character with a stringstream object.

I know when type this:

```
stringstream stringObj;
stringObj << "Type Line 1 \rType Line 2";
CCLabel label = ...;
label->setString(stringObj->str()->c_str());
```

Output from string Obj

```
Type Line 1
Type Line 2
```

But when I read in from a char*, the \r is read in literally.

```
char* charString = GetMyAppString(stringkey);//returns char* to string "Type Line 1\rType Line 2"
stringstream stringObj;
stringObj << charString;
CCLabel label = ...;
label->setString(stringObj->str()->c_str());
```

I get the literal of the string.

```
Type Line 1\rType Line 2
```

What can I do to read this string and get it formatted like in my first output example?
My goal is to take my character sequence from a char* and have the formatting apply (with \n or \r).  It doesnt have to be a stringstream, but nothing else seems to work...

Comment: Is the character sequence you are getting is '\\', 'r' or '\r'?

Comment: It is \r when the stringstream uses a char* for input, but when I do a string literal "Type Line 1\rType Line 2", the new line is properly handled, but with a char* it reads it literally, and doesnt format it.